# fsadm: Cannot get FSTYPE of "/dev/mapper/virtual--machines-lvol0". Filesystem check failed

Tags: 20.04

I'm currently trying to expand the alloted hard drive space on this server.  When I do a `fdisk -l` I get the following

```
/home/api# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 99.22 MiB, 104030208 bytes, 203184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.48 MiB, 58159104 bytes, 113592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 99.15 MiB, 103964672 bytes, 203056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 69.9 MiB, 73277440 bytes, 143120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 55.46 MiB, 58142720 bytes, 113560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 70.39 MiB, 73797632 bytes, 144136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 800 GiB, 858993459200 bytes, 1677721600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A078CCF8-9233-43B5-AF50-32ABC1E5FB18

Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096  167770111  167766016   80G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  167770112 1677721566 1509951455  720G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/virtual--machines-lvol0: 719.102 GiB, 773089918976 bytes, 1509941248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

But when I run the command `resize2fs -r /dev/sda3` I get the following error

```
/home/api# lvextend -r -l+100%FREE /dev/virtual-machines/lvol0
fsadm: Cannot get FSTYPE of "/dev/mapper/virtual--machines-lvol0".
  Filesystem check failed.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### The answer

Your issue is most likely due to not having an FS created on the LV you're trying to extend.

If you're trying to extend `/dev/virtual-machines/lvol0`, I suggest you make sure it has an FS first by running:

`lsblk -f /dev/virtual-machines/lvol0`

If the column FSTYPE shows nothing, then you have to create an FS. To create an ext4 FS run:

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/virtual-machines/lvol0`

This will create an FS on the full extent of that LV, so no need to do a resize after that. However, if later you were to add an extra Physical Volume to your Volume Group, you can then extend your Logical Volume with the command you used to try and do so, though I prefer the following syntax for cases like this one:

`lvextend -r /dev/virtual-machines/lvol0 /dev/sdaX`

This adds all space from the specified PV to the LV. Just in case clarification is needed:

- `-r`: Also resizes the FS.
- `/dev/sdaX`: This is the newly added PV, which has to be in the same VG as the other PVs of this LV.

​

#### Some final comments

**-** You said that you run the command `resize2fs -r /dev/sda3` but you showed the output for the command `lvextend -r -l+100%FREE /dev/virtual-machines/lvol0`. I just looked past by it and assumed it was a mistake.

**-** When working with Logical Volumes, you should not manage the FS directly on the "physical" partitions (`/dev/sda3`, in this case); only work on the LV itself.

**-** Please also note that, when working with LVM, your partitions should be of type "Linux LVM". I run some tests and didn't encounter any issue with using partition type "Linux" instead of "Linux LVM", I even changed back and forth from one to the other without losing any data or having any negative impact whatsoever on a running system but, just in case, I suggest you use the corresponding partition type to avoid any possible issues.

In case you need to know how to change a partition type, assuming that the partition of interest is `/dev/sda3`:

1. As we do every time before we work with stuff related to storage, back up all data you can't afford to lose.
2. Run `fdisk /dev/sda` (you'll be taken to the fdisk tool).
3. Just to be on the safe side, press `p` to print the partition table and check its current status.
4. Press `t` to change the type of a partition.
5. Press `3` to select partition number 3. If you only have one partition (number 1), said partition will be automatically selected.
6. Press `l` to list all available partition types and look for the one corresponding to "Linux LVM".
7. Input the number you found on the previous step (could be a hex number) and press `Enter`.
8. Again, to be on the safe side, press `p` to check your changes.
9. If you're ready to save and quit, press `w`. If having any doubts and want to revert the whole process, you may quit without saving by pressing `q`.